# PrimeNg Turbo table export row with object

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable, primeng, export-csv

I am trying to export the data from a primeng turbo table to a csv.
The problem is 'rows' here in the code below is an array of objects which i display in the table body using ngIf based on the keys accordingly, so displaying is not a problem, but when i try to export to csv i get the object in the cell rather than the object property.
Is there a way to get the object property using datatable.exportCSV()

Here is what i am working on

```
 <p-table #dt [columns]="cols" [value]="rows" selectionMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selectedResults">

<ng-template pTemplate="caption">
Test Set - {{testsetid}}
<div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
  <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-file-o" iconPos="left" label="All Data" (click)="dt.exportCSV()" style="float:left"></button>
  <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-file" iconPos="left" label="Selection Only" (click)="dt.exportCSV({selectionOnly:true})" style="float:right"></button>
</div>

 </ng-template>
 <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
<tr>
  <th *ngFor="let col of cols">
    {{col.header}}
  </th>
  </tr>
 </ng-template>
 <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row let-columns="cols">
   <tr [pSelectableRow] = "row">
  <td *ngFor="let col of cols" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getColor(row[col.field]['status'])}">
    <span *ngIf="col.field == 'script_name'" >{{row[col.field]}}</span>
    <span *ngIf="col.field != 'script_name'" >
      <a [routerLink]="['/localrunreport' , row[col.field]['sessionId']]"> {{row[col.field]['status']}}</a>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
</ng-template>



</p-table>
```

This is what i get in the csv file:
[exported csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETfLU.jpg)

It is happening because of the array of the objects being of type :

```
[{'script_name': value, 'device_name':{'status':value,'sessionId':value}}}
```

So as you can see the issue is all because  device_name key has a value of an object.Is there a way i can have the obj property in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your HTML look like

```
<tr>
  <td *ngFor="let col of cols">
    {{row[col.field]}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

by transferring your HTML *ngIf* conditions in your TS code.

Then you should be able to directly export the values.

Comment: yeah, seems like changing  the TS is the only way out.